# To show Urysohn function is continuous at any arbitrary point directly

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I have to show that the **Urysohn function** 
$f$ defined from $X$ to $[0,1]$ is continuous at any arbitrary point $x_0 \in X$ directly. (I am aware that $f(x)$ is continuous on $X$, but here my problem is to show that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ directly).
where the Urysohn function is $$f(x) = \inf\{ t \in \mathbb Q : x \in F_t\} , $$ where $\{F_t : t \in \mathbb Q \}$ is a family of open sets in $(X, \mathcal T)$ which satisfy the following properties :

- $F_t = \emptyset$ for $t \lt 0$.
- $F_t = X $ for $t \gt 1$.
- For $ t \lt s , \overline{F_t} \subset F_s$. (Bar denotes the closure of the set.)

To show $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ , I have to show that for any arbitrary neighborhood $W$ of $f(x_0)$ there exist a neighborhood $V$ of $x_0$ such that $f(V) \subset W$. Also any neighborhood of $f(x_0)$ contains an open interval $(p,q)$ , but after this I lost the way to think.

Any insight will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: for $s < f(x_0) < t$, consider the set $F_t \setminus \overline{F_s}$.

Try to prove the following:

1. $x ∈ \overline{F_t} \implies f(x) ≤ t$,

   $x ∉ F_t \implies f(x) ≥ t$,

   $x ∈ \overline{F_t} \setminus F_s \implies f(x) ∈ [s, t]$,

   $f(x) ∈ (s, t) \implies x ∈ F_t \setminus \overline{F_s}$.

Comment: The set is clearly open ! And I am unable to say more than that ! @user87690

Comment: Yes, it is open. But is it a neihgborhood of $x_0$? What can you cay about values of $f$ on this set?

Comment: For any $x$ in $F_t \setminus \overline F_s $ , $f(x)$ is by definition I think $s$ which is in $[s,t]$ $\subset V$ , so the set is a subset of $(f)^-¹(V)$. Right ?

Comment: What is $V$? Before you called a given neighborhood of $f(x_0)$ by $W$, and $V$ should have been a suitable neighborhood of $x_0$. Also, you cannot denote $f(x)$ by $s$ when $s$ is already used.

Comment: Then what is the value of $f$ there ? I am not visualising it properly !.

Comment: Ok, let's start with this: if $x ∈ F_t$, then what can you say about $f(x)$?

Comment: It's the infimum of all rationals s  for which $x \in F_s$ , so I think.... Actually I can't get it , as that $x$ can be in any $F_k$ for any $k \lt t $.

Comment: But that doesn't matter. Since $x ∈ F_t$, we have $t ∈ \{s ∈ ℚ: x ∈ F_s\}$. So how is $t$ related to the infimum of that set, which is $f(x)$?

Comment: I think $f(x) \le t $

Comment: Sure. Similarly, if $x ∉ F_t$, can you relate $f(x)$ and $t$?

Comment: Ok , then $f(x) \gt t $.

Comment: Oh ! Then I guess for all $x \in$ the set you told me to consider $ s \lt f(x) \le t $.

Comment: You have, $t < \{s: x ∈ F_s\}$, so just $t ≤ f(x)$. It can be equal. Otherwise, you are right. I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: I think I have proved it. Thanks for your hints and for your patience @user87690 !